# Ethernet driver Power Mangement bug workaround

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, power-management, wake-on-lan

I think I have found a bug in the Power Management settings of the ethernet drivers in Windows 10 (see: Control Panel / Device Manager / Network adapters / %my ethernet card% / Properties / Power Management).

Usually it has three items (see the inserted picture). If the first option is disabled (grayed) (computer not allowed to turn off the device) then (IMHO) the other two should be enabled (shown in black) (computer is allowed wake the computer). I tested and the first setting, really does what it states, so if it is enabled and the computer goes to power off state, it really turns off the LAN card (link led goes off). So, when it is checked it make no sense to enable the wake on LAN feature as the card is in powerless state and cannot sense the request.

The only way to enable the Wake On Lan feature to check the first option then check the other two, then uncheck the first option (graying the other two rows, but keeping their checked state). In this state it does what it states, so the computer can be turned on by sending a magic package to it.

I would like to enable the "Wake on Pattern Match" feature, so to wake up the PC when a TCP connection is initiated to the machine. But I cannot set this state (the first and third option should be unchecked and the second checked). I tried to check and uncheck them in different order and pressing OK to save the set values, but after boot either the second become unchecked or the third become checked. BTW in the LAN card's Advanced Settings I enabled the "Wake on Pattern Match" feature and unchecked the "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" setting in Power Options but I cannot wake the PC.

I was thinking about to use `regedit`, but I could not find this setting. I also tried to connect to Intel, but this card is an OEM product. Then I tried to connect to Lenovo, but they kind of ping-ponged with me. :)

Anyone has an idea to override this issue/bug? Or could anyone make the "Wake on Pattern Match" feature work?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

***UPDATE***

On the net I have found how to get the values connected to this settings:

`Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -RegistryKeyword PnPCapabilities  -AllProperties`

This returns values like

```
Name                      DisplayName                    DisplayValue                   RegistryKeyword RegistryValue
----                      -----------                    ------------                   --------------- -------------
Ethernet                  --                             --                             PnPCapabilities {24}
```

I searched the registry with `regedit` for `PnPCapabilities` and I found the following registry entry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001
```

(the last 0001 if just for my machine. On other machine is can be some other number)

Here one can find the `PnPCapabilities`, which can be coded as:

(negated 1st option)*8 + (negated 2nd option) * 16 + (3rd option) * 256

So if I want only 2nd to be set, I have to set this value to `8`.

***UPDATE***

I tried and it does not wake up for TCP SYN. I did some research and I think I have to write a small code to upload the required pattern to the NIC and if this pattern matches the received packet the PC should be awakened.

Comment: WOL works even if the computer is shut down, if the NIC & mobo fully support the protocol - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN Your checkbox 3 is a subset of 2. Enabling both is what you actually need. Checkbox 1 is [or ought to be] independent, but not exclusive. Being powered down is part of the WOL protocol.

Comment: @Tetsujin: WOL works only if the LAN card it not powered off when the PC is turned off.

Comment: as I said… "if the NIC & mobo fully support the protocol" WOL is designed to be able to boot a computer that has been completely shut down.

Comment: @Tetsujin: as I said if the LAN card is turned off (powered down, Ethernet Link LED is off) it cannot wake the PC. This is for energy saving reason. If the LAN card is on while the PC is off it eats 1.2W. This is what the first setting controls! I have tried it, and believe me, it works properly! :)

Comment: So your system doesn't support the protocol. If "Off" means no signal can be received & passed to the mobo & PSU… then you're stuck. Your equipment does not fully support WOL.

Comment: My system does support the WoL protocol. If the 1st option is unchecked and the 2nd and 3rd are checked (and some more other setting are set properly) I can wake up my PC from hibernation (S3) and power off (S5) state sending the magic package to the pc. It works nicely!

Comment: Have you tried updating the drivers from the manufacturers website? Also, what kind of settings do you have for the NIC in the bios?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart: Yes! The latest driver for `Intel® Ethernet Connection I217-LM` is [Intel Network Adapter Drivers for Windows 10](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Ethernet-Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10?product=60019) v24.3. Installed, but the driver itself was not updated (driver version: 12.18.9.10, date: 2019-07-25). The driver works well. IMHO the Windows 10 Power Management page is buggy. I cannot turn off `Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer` setting while setting `Allow the device to wake the computer` (also turning off the 1st option).

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I downloaded the documentation of the PROSet utility for Inter device driver configuration and I found a nice note: `The Intel® PROSet for Windows Device Manager is not available on Microsoft* Windows
Server* 2019 and Microsoft Windows* 10 Version 1809 (and later.`. So, it seems there is not hope... :(